# How can I parse this html?

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape https://PickleballBrackets.com using Selenium and BeautifulSoup with this code:

```
browser = webdriver.Safari()
browser.get('https://pickleballbrackets.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
```

If I look at browser.page_source after I get the html, I can see 50 instances of

```
<div class="browse-row-box">
```

but after I create a soup object, they are lost. I believe that means that I have poorly formed html. I've tried all three parsers ('lxml', 'html5lib', 'html.parser') without any luck.

Suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Make sure your code is a [mre]. Also, you're not really doing *anything* with the soup. so how come you know there are 50 instances of that class?

Comment: When I inspect browser.page_source in my debugger, I can see the 50 instances of <div class="browse-row-box">. If I inspect the soup variable in the debugger, there are no instances. Also, if I do a soup.find('div', class_="browse-row-box"), I get a result of None.

Comment: There's no such thing as "poorly formed HTML". The browser will parse the invalid HTML into a correctly-structured DOM.

Comment: Wait for the page to fully load and then try looking for that class.

Comment: Thank you baduker, you are correct. The page had not full loaded. A sleep(10) statement did the trick. Now I'll look for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing, `soup.find()` returns a single item.

Answer (score 0):

Lot easier to get the data from the source.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://pickleballbrackets.com/Json.asmx/EventsSearch_PublicUI'
payload = {
'AgeIDs': "",
'Alpha': "All",
'ClubID': "",
'CountryID': "",
'DateFilter': "future",
'EventTypeIDs': "1",
'FormatIDs': "",
'FromDate': "",
'IncludeTestEvents': "0",
'OrderBy': "EventActivityFirstDate",
'OrderDirection': "Asc",
'PageNumber': "1",
'PageSize': 9999,
'PlayerGroupIDs': "",
'PrizeMoney': "All",
'RankIDs': "",
'ReturnType': "json",
'SearchWord': "",
'ShowOnCalendar': "0",
'SportIDs': "dc1894c6-7e85-43bc-bfa2-3993b0dd630f",
'StateIDs': "",
'ToDate': "",
'prt': ""}

jsonData = requests.post(url, json=payload).json()


df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['d'])
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.head(2).to_string())
   RowNumber  RecordCount  PageCount  CurrPage                               EventID                                ClubID                                        Title TimeZoneAbbreviation  UTCOffset  HasDST  StartTimesPosted                                           Logo  OnlineRegistration_Active Registration_DateOpen Registration_DateClosed  IsSanctioned  CancelTourney LocationOfEvent_Venue LocationOfEvent_StreetAddress LocationOfEvent_City LocationOfEvent_CountryTitle LocationOfEvent_StateTitle LocationOfEvent_Zip  ShowDraws  IsFavorite  IsPrizeMoney  MaxRegistrationsForEntireEvent  Sanction_PCO SanctionLevelAppovedStatus_PCO SanctionLevelID_PCO  Sanction_SSIPA SanctionLevelAppovedStatus_SSIPA SanctionLevelID_SSIPA  Sanction_USAPA SanctionLevelAppovedStatus_USAP SanctionLevelID_USAP  Sanction_WPF SanctionLevelAppovedStatus_WPF SanctionLevelID_WPF  Sanction_GPA SanctionLevelAppovedStatus_GPA SanctionLevelID_GPA EventActivityFirstDate EventActivityLastDate  IsRegClosed  Cost_Registration_Current  Cost_FeeOnEvents  RegistrationCount_InAtLeastOneLiveEvent  showResultsButton SantionLevels_PCO_Title SantionLevels_PCO_LevelLogo SantionLevels_SSIPA_Title SantionLevels_SSIPA_LevelLogo SantionLevels_USAP_Title SantionLevels_USAP_LevelLogo SantionLevels_WPF_Title SantionLevels_WPF_LevelLogo SantionLevels_GPA_Title SantionLevels_GPA_LevelLogo  mng
0          1          152          1         1  410d04c2-49c5-48a4-847f-0f0ac0aa92f7  91c83e9c-c8e3-460d-b124-52f5c1036336  Cincinnati Pickleball Club 2022 March Mania                  EST         -5    True             False  410d04c2-49c5-48a4-847f-0f0ac0aa92f7_Logo.png                       True  1/24/2022 7:30:00 AM    3/22/2022 5:00:00 PM         False          False     Five Seasons Ohio             11790 Snider Road           Cincinnati                United States                       Ohio               45249         -1           0         False                               0         False                                                              False                                                                  False                                                              False                                                            False                                                      3/25/2022 4:00:00 PM  3/27/2022 2:00:00 PM            1                       50.0             225.0                                      238                  1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0
1          2          152          1         1  9f0c5976-94e9-4d58-a273-774744bdacec  e5cd380b-fe72-4ef4-89e8-5053e94587a3       Flash Fridays Slam Series - March 25th                  EST         -5    True             False  9f0c5976-94e9-4d58-a273-774744bdacec_Logo.png                       True   3/1/2022 5:00:00 PM   3/23/2022 11:45:00 PM         False          False         Holbrook Park               100 Sherwood Dr         Huntersville                United States             North Carolina               28078          1           0         False                               6         False                                                              False                                                                  False                                                              False                                                            False                                                      3/25/2022 4:00:00 PM  3/25/2022 4:00:00 PM            1                       25.0               0.0                                        0                  0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0
....

[152 rows x 60 columns]
```